# Two namespaces of the same class

Tags: c#, namespaces

we are changing the name of our product, so i also want to rename the namespaces of our
framework-classes. But now i have the problem, that i don't know in which programms and scripts our namespaces are used. Is there a way in c#, to locate the same class in two different namespaces?

I know the solution, that i could inherited from my classes in the new namespace, but this is a very bad solution i think. So I have no idea how to solve this problem, because simply renaming all namespaces doesn't help and will cause a lot trouble.

Thank you!

Comment: Would it be hard to create a new version of the assembly? You can also look at type forwarding.

Comment: That would not solve the problem, because i use the assemblies in python scripts and if i create a new verion and deploy it, the scripts won't work anymore.

Comment: Then use the old version, this is what versioning is all about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If external scripts are referencing your assembly using the old namespace names then those names will have to remain in your assembly in you wish to continue to use those scripts. If you also want to create new namespace names to reflect the new name of your product, those names will also need to be hardcoded into your assembly. This will inevitably lead to problems!

I would recommend one of the following:

1. Leave the namespace names as they are.
2. Rename the namespaces in full and update the Python scripts at the same time.

I would definitely not recommend the faux 'inheritance' method, or any other solution which results in duplication within the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You could search the whole project / solution of course, but that seems sort of messy and time-consuming too, if you've got more than a trivial project.

Are you using Resharper? For this type of task, you definitely should be. If so, there is a chance this could at least help you on your way:

- Rename the folders your source files are in in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer (this should in theory be easier than looking at each source file one by one, right?).
- Now open one source file that you know will have the wrong namespace due to a renamed folder. It should appear with a blue squiggly line, as in the picture below.
- Use the Resharper tip (pyramid to the left, or `Alt + Enter`) to open the context meny thingy also shown below.
- Select *Find all issues of this type in scope*, and select *Solution* as your scope. That might at least help you get an overview of which classes you need to change the namespaces for, and go through them and change them systematically.

[image]

As for your scripts, I would guess that you best bet is to do a plain text search for the old namespaces - possibly a *search and replace*. Perhaps you can include your scripts in a VS solution, and use the built in search there to scan and fix them. That might at least ease the pain a little..